# Can we apply no hair theorem to neutron stars?

Tags: neutron-stars

As neutron stars are composed of neutrons only and we can't know where the neutron comes from (eg: from what atoms), does neutron stars also fulfill no hair theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because neutron stars can have all sorts of complicated structure, and also aren't in fact composed entirely of neutrons at all, just *almost* entirely.

A vacuum solution like a BH is an entirely simpler animal.